# line break inside tikz node pin

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I get the line break inside a pin node to work in TikZ?

```
\node[pin={\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:hi\\there}] at (120:3) {};
```

I tried `align=center` but didn't work as a typical node.

Comment: Try `\node[pin={[align=center]45:hi\\there}] at (120:3) {};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[pin={[align=center]30:{hi\\ there}}] at (120:3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]